# When trying to run "Friday Night Funkin" I get an X Error (BadValue)

Tags: command-line, executable

I get this when trying to run the game:

```
joe@joe-epic-laptop:~/Downloads/funkin$ ./Funkin 
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  72
  Current serial number in output stream:  73
```

Comment: No information here that could be used to even start to help. What version of Ubuntu? Is this a Steam game or a wine game or what? How was it installed?

Comment: @David sorry! im using the latest LTS release of xubuntu, its a native linux game and according to instructions i only need to make it executable and do ./Funkin . i installed it from the official site

Comment: When i try to run the windows edition using wine the same thing happens,

Answer (score 0):

The official site https://ninja-muffin24.itch.io/funkin just offers to download a .zip (!) file without any instructions, and being a .zip file and not a proper package in any of the Linux package formats (.deb, .rpm, ...) makes it impossible to ensure all the required runtime dependencies are present. This is just sloppy.

The GitHub sources at https://github.com/ninjamuffin99/Funkin have some instructions how to install this, but it also says:

> I'm too lazy to write and keep updated with that setup

which I find telling all by itself.

I'd stay away from such low-quality software. Can you be sure that it doesn't do anything harmful to your system?